# how to install/use biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib

I recently decided to change from `natbib` to `biblatex`, however I'm having some trouble using `biblatex`. My bare bones document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myrefs.bib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\textcite{dynamicCouplingMarketInst}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and I have replaced all citations with `\textcite` however the bibliography now does not show up at the end of the document, and the citations now just show the citation alias in bold instead of the actual details. Basic question I know, but do you have to manually install `biblatex`? I was using `natbib` fine previously. I'm on a mac, and I have BibTeX installed. I'm using Texpad as an editor and have run BibTeX after the change.

**UPDATE 2**: Thanks all for your help, I have added the option of `backend=bibtext` when loading the `biblatex` package, however that caused the following two errors:

> `apa.bbx - datelabel undefined`

and

> `thesistemplate.tex - Package biblatex Error: backend=biber required by style (\begin{document})`

and my bib engine is **now Biber**!

**these errors are now gone, I deleted the `.bbl` file and cleared the biber cache and the errors disappeared, however the bibliography and citations are still not showing.**

In the log, for each of my citations, it says:

> `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'citation name' on page x undefined on input line y`

.BIB file:

```
@article{flashBoys,
  title     = {Flash Boys: Cracking the money code},
  author    = "Michael Lewis",
  year      = "2014",
  publisher = "The Penguin Group, London, England"
}

@article{cohen2012limit,
  title={A limit order book model for latency arbitrage},
  author={Cohen, Samuel N and Szpruch, Lukasz},
  journal={Mathematics and Financial Economics},
  volume={6},
  number={3},
  pages={211--227},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{LatencyArbitrageTheRealPower,
  title     = {Latency Arbitrage: The Real Power Behind Predatory High Frequency Trading},
  author    = "Sal Arnuk and Joseph Saluzzi",
  year      = "2009"
  publisher = "Themis Trading LLC"
}

@inproceedings{wah2013latency,
  title={Latency arbitrage, market fragmentation, and efficiency: a two-market model},
  author={Wah, Elaine and Wellman, Michael P},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the fourteenth ACM conference on Electronic commerce},
  pages={855--872},
  year={2013},
  organization={ACM}
}

@article{colocationAdvantage,
  title     = {High-Frequency Trading: The Co-Location Advantage},
  url       = "https://blog.lordabbett.com/blog/2014/05/high-frequency_trading_the_co-      location_advantage.html",
  author    = "Ted Oberhaus",
  year      = "2014"
}

@article{programmingInMiranda,
  title     = {Programming with Miranda},
  author    = "Chris Clack and Colin Myers and Ellen Poon",
  year      = "2011"
}


@article{dynamicCouplingMarketInst,
  title     = {Dynamic Coupling and Market Instability},
  author    = "Chris Clack and Elias Court and Dmitrijs Zaparanuks",
  year      = "2014"
}

@article{michaelLewisWrong,
    title  = {Michael Lewis Is Entirely Wrong About High Frequency Trading Hitting The Little Guy},
    author = "Tim Worstall",
    publisher = "Forbes"
    year    = "2014",
    url     = "http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2014/03/31/michael-lewis-is-entirely-wrong-about-high-frequency-trading-hitting-the-little-guy/"   

}  

@article{naturalGasLeak,
    title  = {Natural Gas Leak},
    author = "Eric Hunsader",
    publisher = "Nanex",
    year      = "2013",
    url       = "http://www.nanex.net/aqck2/4090.html"  
}

@article{marketMakerInvestopedia,
    title  = {Market Maker Definition},
    author = "Investopedia",
    year   = "2014",
    url    = "http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marketmaker.asp"
}

@article{greatFedRobbery,
    title  = {Einstein and The Great Fed Robbery},
    author = "Eric Hunsader",
    year   = "2013",
    url    = "http://www.nanex.net/aqck2/4436.html",
    publisher = "Nanex"
}


@article{flashTrading,
    title  = {Flash Trading Definition},
    author = "Investopedia",
    year   = "2014",
    url    = "http://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/flash-trading.asp"
}


@article{brunnermeier2005predatory,
  title={Predatory trading},
  author={Brunnermeier, Markus K and Pedersen, Lasse Heje},
  journal={The Journal of Finance},
  volume={60},
  number={4},
  pages={1825--1863},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

Comment: Did you run biber? What does the .blg-file say?

Comment: you have to change the bibliography engine. By default it is `biber`, not `bibtex`. You have to go the preference pane of texpad, and change it there

Comment: My default bibliography engine is set to bibtex already. I had it set as that when using natbib previously.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm using Bibtex so don't have a .blg file unfortunately.

Comment: To use BibTeX with `biblatex`, add `backend=bibtex` as an option when loading the package. The run LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX: you should see your citations appear.

Comment: @JustinMoser, `bibtex` also produces a `.blg` file (you can call it a bibliography log file)

Comment: You have to change the engine to `biber` or use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`

Comment: biber is not bibtex. You will have to run biber with using biblatex. (Well you could also use bibtex, but it is not recommended as a lot of features are biber only).

Comment: To have the actual details, you can add an option when loading biblatex: `citestyle=verbose`. This make the citation identical to the full bib entry the first time it's used. If you want *always*  the full citation, replace `\cite` with `\fullcite`. You should take a look at the doc, §3 et, to begin with, § 3.1.

Comment: The error messages are telling you that the `apa` style requires you to run `biber` instead of `bibtex`.  Standard distributions should have `biber` included.

Comment: Thanks. How strange. I've switched to Biber now (although I don't get an option to run Biber in Texpad, only Bibtex). When I re compile it all, I get hundreds of undefined control sequence errors from the .bbl file. Additionally, in the log file, regardless of which bib engine I choose, all the output mentions is Bibtex.

Comment: Did you also removed the backend=bibtex option in your tex file? Did you delete the bbl-file and run a new compilation? (One always gets errors when one changes the backend option if one doesn't delete the bbl-file first). Beside this: Update also your example if you get new errors so that we know what you are actually trying to compile. The example above doesn't use apa.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer I have now updated the example to show my document fully. The errors have disappeared, but for some reason I still have no bib or citations.

Comment: @JustinMoser You need to run `biber` now instead of `bibtex`. You run in the same procedure as you would for `bibtex`, just substitute `biber` instead of `bibtex` (`pdflatex` `biber` `pdflatex` `pdflatex`)

Comment: @darthbith I'm using texpad, so in the typesetter menu I just run bibtex (which apparently is the general name for compiling the bibliography) and then the Normal typesetter (which runs pdflatex I imagine).

Comment: In the example you are not citing anything. You need a \cite{...} or \nocite{*} command. If you are actually compiling something else with a cite command: show the true example and also show the content of the blg-file.

Comment: @JustinMoser According to the docs here: https://www.texpadapp.com/static/guides/osx/help.pdf I think you have to set which engine to use (`bibtex` or `biber`) in the Preferences (see page 6). Did you change that? Also, what Ulrike Fischer said...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ive added one of my citations. My document is huge so it wouldnt make much sense to list it all. I dont think I have a .blg file. I've also listed the contents of my .bib file.

Comment: Don't test biblatex/biber with a huge document. Create a small document in a test folder. Then you can also show us your real document when you have problems and not fake something. I really don't want to wast my time to try out examples that aren't real. And you must have a `blg` if biber did run (and if you don't use some overeager editor or script that deletes the file). If you have windows: check if windows hides the extension.

Comment: Sure will do. I just had a look in the .blg file (it was being instantly removed by the editor) and it says 'cannot find myrefs!" which I guess is the root cause...odd as it's the editor that created the .bib file when I first included biblatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your bib entrys `LatencyArbitrageTheRealPower` and `michaelLewisWrong` is a comma missing. Add them and everything should compile.

Here the two corrected bib entrys:

```
@article{LatencyArbitrageTheRealPower,
  title     = {Latency Arbitrage: The Real Power Behind Predatory High Frequency Trading},
  author    = {Sal Arnuk and Joseph Saluzzi},
  year      = {2009},
  publisher = {Themis Trading LLC},
}


@article{michaelLewisWrong,
    title  = {Michael Lewis Is Entirely Wrong About High Frequency Trading Hitting The Little Guy},
    author = "Tim Worstall",
    publisher = "Forbes",
    year    = "2014",
    url     = "http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2014/03/31/michael-lewis-is-entirely-wrong-about-high-frequency-trading-hitting-the-little-guy/"   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it! I spend an aaage trying to spot the issue. I must have missed it. Tired eyes!

Comment: I've accepted the answer, however I need a little more reputation to up vote it, otherwise I definitely would! Sorry!